# in NextJS, Next-Auth signIn is not working with error - "ikm" must be at least one byte in length

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm integrating next-auth package to my fresh Next.js project.

```
"next": "13.4.19",
"next-auth": "^4.23.1",
```

> pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default async function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        id: 'credentials',
        name: 'Credentials',
        credentials: {
          email: {
            label: 'Email',
            type: 'text',
          },
          password: {
            label: 'Password',
            type: 'password',
          },
        },
        async authorize(credentials) {
  
          console.log('credentials',credentials);   
          const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/signin", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
          })
          const data = await res.json()
          if (res.ok && data) {
            return data;
          }
          return null;      
        },
      }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/',
    },
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    session: {
      strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    jwt: {
      secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_JWT_SECRET,
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  })
}
```

login page

> /app/auth/login/page.tsx

```
const onLogin = async () => {
    try {
        setLoading(true)

        console.log('signIn',user);
        const result = await signIn("credentials", {
            email: user?.email,
            password: user?.password,
            redirect: false,
          });

        console.log('get user ',result);
        toast.success("Login Successfull")
        router.push("/profile")
        
    } catch (error: any) {
        toast.error("Email or Password is incorrect", error.message)
    }finally{
        setLoading(false)
    }
}
```

I checked the auth providers, showing

```
credentials{
   callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials"
   id: "credentials"
   name: "Credentials"
   signinUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/credentials"
   type: "credentials"
}
```

when clicking the login button, I expect to see the console message with credential and http request to *http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/signin*

```
    async authorize(credentials) {

      console.log('credentials',credentials);   

      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/signin", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      })
   ....
```

but the developer console only shows

**http://localhost:4000/api/auth/callback/credentials? 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause to this problem is the missing of NEXTAUTH_JWT_SECRET in

```
jwt: {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_JWT_SECRET,
}
```

providing this will be ok